# Forcing matlab ODE solvers to use dy/dx = 0 IF dy/dx is negative

Tags: matlab, ode

I need to numerically integrate the following system of ODEs:

dA/dR = f(R,A,B)
dB/dR = g(R,A,B)

I'm solving the ODEs for a Initial-value stability problem. In this problem, the system is initially stable but goes unstable at some radius. However, whilst stable, I don't want the amplitude to decay away from the starting value (to O(10^-5) for example) as this is non-physical since the system's stability is limited to the background noise amplitude. The amplitude should remain at the starting value of 1 until the system destabilises. Hence, I want to overwrite the derivative estimate to zero whenever it is negative.

I've written some 4th order Runge-Kutta code that achieves this, but I'd much prefer to simply pass ODE45 (or any of the built in solvers) a parameter to make it overwrite the derivative whenever it is negative. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple, fast, efficient way to implement this is via the `max` function. For example, if you want to make sure all of your derivatives remain non-negative, in your integration function:

```
function ydot = f(x,y)
ydot(1) = ...
ydot(2) = ...
...
ydot = max(ydot,0);
```

Note that this is not the same thing as the output states returned by `ode45` remaining non-negative. The above should ensure that your state variables never decay.

Note, however, that that this effectively makes your integration function stiff. You might consider using a solver like `ode15s` instead, or at least confirming that the results are consistent with those from `ode45`. Alternatively, you could use a continuous [sigmoid function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function), instead of the discontinuous, step-like `max`. This is partly a modeling decision.

Comment: that works very well thank you. However, after destabilising, my system then becomes stable again at a later radius still. Your suggestion above leads to the amplitude of the state variable flattening out at the maximum instead of returning to the background noise amplitude upon re-stabilisation since, as you say, the state variables never decay. Do you suggest an IF y>0 condition on the MAX line above or is there a better way?

Comment: The `max` function is just a convenient faster version of an `if` statement. Your question asked how to "force solvers to use dy/dx = 0 IF dy/dx is negative." By definition this implies that you don't want y to ever decay. If this is not true, then maybe there is something you're not understanding or you haven't described the problem correctly. It's hard to say much without seeing code or even the actual ODEs. Perhaps, you want actually want to ensure the resultant `y` returned by `ode45` after integration is always non-negative? If so, this answer will be completely different.

Comment: Apologies - I hadn't described the problem correctly. I do want the state variables to decay back to the background noise amplitude when the system is stable, but then not decay below that level. Doing as you've suggested, but inside an IF loop such that it only applies to prevent decay below the noise level, has given me the results I wanted.

Comment: @user3648565: Yes, sounds like a more complex criterion than in your question. If you have noise in your system than you should definitely be using `ode15s` or another stiff solver instead of `ode45`. And note that if your system is actually a stochastic differential equation (SDE) and/or you you're modeleing Gaussian noise then you can't use any of the ODE solvers and guarantee correct results.